# Exchange webservice mail banner

Tags: vb.net, outlook, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2010

How do I add text to a received mail message with exchange web services 2010 on the place where stands “you have forwarded this message on” ?

Comment: Please, give us a snippet of what you tried in order to recreate the issue and understand better your problem

Comment: That’s the problem I guess. I can loop through the mail messages, no problem. I don’t know what type of object the banner is. In outlook it appears as a little blue question mark in the header of the mail message  with the text that the message has been forwarded or replied. Just above from who it is received and cc etc. I hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: E-mails are usually just HTML code. Lookup how you can view the e-mail source in your mail client in order to determine what the banner actually is.

Answer (score 0):

You don't that banner is calculated by the client from two properties eg the PidTagLastVerbExecuted https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/pidtaglastverbexecuted-canonical-property is used to determine the action eg (a value of 104 would mean the message was forwarded) and then PidTagLastVerbExecutionTime https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/pidtaglastverbexecutiontime-canonical-property is used to determine the time the action took place.

You may want to look at the "X-Message-Flag" header in a Message which is another way of doing something similar.

Comment: That helps. Any idea how to set a custom text in the banner?

Comment: Look at using X-Message-Flag

Comment: Do you have a sample for me?